# Create users in SofEther VPN using Python

Tags: python, vpn, l2tp

Using a Python script, I fetch users plus their expiration date from a MySQL database. Since SofEther VPN accepts DateTime value and I stored expiration date as Date value in the database, a formatted version is passed to the SoftEther. Although after running the script I get the below message, still SoftEther VPN Manager shows that expiration date for the corresponding users has not been set:

> vpncmd command - SoftEther VPN Command Line Management Utility
> SoftEther VPN Command Line Management Utility (vpncmd command)
> Version 4.43 Build 9799   (English)
> Compiled 2023/08/31 10:50:49 by buildsan at crosswin with OpenSSL 3.0.9
> Copyright (c) 2012-2023 SoftEther VPN Project. All Rights Reserved.
>
> Connection has been established with VPN Server "localhost" (port 443).
>
> You have administrator privileges for the entire VPN Server.
>
> The Virtual Hub "VPN" has been selected.
> VPN Server/VPN>UserExpiresSet h31403 /EXPIRES: 2024/11/30 00:00:00
> UserExpiresSet command - Set User's Expiration Date
> The command completed successfully.

This part of my script handles the job of setting expiration date for SoftEther users.

```
def set_user_expiration(username, expiry_date):
    # Convert the date object to a datetime object at midnight
    expiry_datetime = datetime.combine(expiry_date, time.min)
    # Format the expiration date and time in a format SoftEther understands
    formatted_expiry_date = expiry_datetime.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    # Command to set the expiration date for a user
    expiration_cmd = f"/server {server}:{port} /adminhub:{hub} /PASSWORD:{admin_password} /CMD UserExpiresSet {username} /EXPIRES: {formatted_expiry_date}"

    # Execute the command
    subprocess.run([vpncmd_path] + expiration_cmd.split(), shell=False)
```